# Copy from an existing RESTful service in Oracle APEX 5?

Tags: rest, oracle-apex

Hello to every one :}

I started working with Oracle Apex for a couple of weeks before. And so some stupied newbwee things takes a lot of time.

So here is my annoying simply newbee question. Is there an easy way to copy an existing RESTful service? As is the case on pages?

For help i would be verrrrrry gladful. :}

Best regards 
your EsKay.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible to copy existing external RESTful service into Oracle APEX. 
You can create RESTful service in Oracle APEX and consume it externally.

Check this documentation from [Creating and Using RESTful Web Service in Application Express 5.0](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r50/Restful%20Services/restful_services.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i will check it out :}